# Limit text box input to maximum value given by property

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I'm working at a WPF app and I have this situation:
- in view model I have two properties: Quantity and Stock
- in view I have a text box which is bind to Quantity
What I want is to allow a maximum Quantity only as many items as Stock says to be entered in the text box. For example if Stock = 3 then whatever number I add into text box for Quantity this to be set to 3 if is higher.

I've tried with the following approach:

```
private int quantity;
public int Quantity
{
    get { return quantity; }
    set
    {
         if (value > Stock)
         {
             quantity = Stock;
         }
         else
         {
             quantity = value;
         }
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
   }   
}
```

The problem of this is that in the view model Quantity is set to Stock but in the view is not updated (if I enter 70 for Quantity then it is set in the view model 3 as Stock is but the view is not updated). The binding of text box is two way with property changed as update source trigger.
I've thinking of working with lost focus for text box. But I feel that this is not the proper way to do it. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of .NET are you running with?  I had _thought_ every WPF version since 4.0 automatically re-read the source property after it's updated by a binding.

Comment: 4.5.1... That's what I knew too. But seems that it does not work here...

Comment: Are you sure you're not clearing your binding accidentally, maybe by setting a local value on `TextBox.Text` in your code-behind?  One thing to try: add a `Converter` to your binding that does nothing but return the original value.  That was the .NET 3.0-era fix for this issue.

Comment: Well, I like to keep the code behind file as clean as possible. Event the button clicks are implemented with commands in view model. So currently without the constructor and init method called inside I have no code behind. I'll try the converter thing and come back with update.

Comment: Wait, is this a UWP app or a WPF app?  Specifically, are you using a UWP or WPF text box?

Comment: Subscribe to `TextBox` event `TextChanging` and check your entered number. Change it with your logic.

Comment: I'm using UWP text box.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem of this is that in the view model Quantity is set to Stock but in the view is not updated (if I enter 70 for Quantity then it is set in the view model 3 as Stock is but the view is not updated). The binding of text box is two way with property changed as update source trigger. I've thinking of working with lost focus for text box.

For your requirement, you could use [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.updatesourcetrigger) to immediately update the source of a TextBox in UWP. For more please refer the following code.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Quantity,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

If you set [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.updatesourcetrigger) as `PropertyChanged`, the binding source is updated whenever the binding target value changes.